# Numerical Optimization subject to multiple constraints

Tags: optimization, numeric

I have a set of 6 variables and some numerical values are available for different settings of variables. The variable *x*, *y* and *z* are all functions of *a*, *b* and *c*. I want to find the optimal setting of *a*, *b* and *c* that minimize *x* subject to

1) *y* = 200 (say);
and
2) *z* < 30 (say)

Comment: How do the functions `x=f(a)`, `y=g(b)` and `z=h(c)` look like?

Comment: They are numerical. I have the data on these variables. Exact form of function is not known.

Comment: and it is like x=f(a,b,c) , y=g(a,b,c) and z=h(a,b,c)

Comment: Then some sort of DFO (Derivative Free Optimization) solver. Black-box problems are not so easy. I avoid them like the plague.

Comment: if I can express x, y and z into a single function, would it make the things easier?

Comment: e.g. find a, b and c that minimize f(a,b,c)

Comment: Here is what I have been trying <br/> *optim(par = c(4,0.6), fn = c(h,k,func), gr = NULL, …, method = "Nelder-Mead", lower = c(1,0.1), upper = c(6,1.5), control = list(), hessian = FALSE)* <br/> ***func*** is what needs to be minimized and it is controlled by ***k*** and ***h***

Comment: There is no h and k in the original description. Anyway, you probably get the best response if you provide some a runnable example. Right now there is very little information and things are a bit contradictory (eg constraints have disappeared from the problem).

Comment: I was able to merge all constraints into a single constrained function (**func**). Now this constrained function depends upon 2 variables ***h*** and ***k***. I want to find the optimal values of ***h*** and ***k*** that minimize the constrained function ***func***. I have around 50 values of ***func*** and their corresponding ***h*** and ***k*** settings.

Answer (score 1):

If all the functions in question are [*linear*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function#As_a_polynomial_function) in regarding to their arguments then this is the problem that [Linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) solves. There are known approaches and algorithms to solve a linear programming problem, your choice depends on other constraints that you did not specify.

Comment: I've never worked with it. May be look at examples?

Comment: Here is what I have been trying <br/> *optim(par = c(4,0.6), fn = c(h,k,func), gr = NULL, …, method = "Nelder-Mead", lower = c(1,0.1), upper = c(6,1.5), control = list(), hessian = FALSE)* <br/> ***func*** is what needs to be minimized and it is controlled by ***k*** and ***h***